# Table Colspan not working when Table tbody set to Display:block;

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with three sections, `thead`, `tbody`, and `tfoot`.

I wanted to have the `tbody` style set to `display:block;` so it would have scrollbars when it got to a certain height. But I noticed when I set the tbody style to `display:block;`, the `colspans` are not working in the table, as if the table is disregarding it. Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this a css3 bug?

> **Please refer to my example HTML & CSS for the table below (with JSfiddle)**

**Here is an image of my problem:**
[image]

**Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:**
[image]

**JSFIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/fT3EC/3/

**TABLE:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="name" colspan="2">Name</td>
            <td class="price">Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="name" colspan="2">Product 1</td>
                <td class="price">$100.00</td>
                <td class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name" colspan="2">Product 2</td>
                <td class="price">$50.00</td>
                <td class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name" colspan="2">Product 3</td>
                <td class="price">$10.00</td>
                <td class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>Sub-Total:</b></td>
                <td>$160.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  colspan="2"><b>Free Shipping:</b></td>
                <td>$0.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  colspan="2"><b>Total:</b></td>
                <td>$160.00</td>
            </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {width:500px;}
tr,td {padding:5px; border:1px solid;}
.price {width:100px;}
.info {width:200px;}

tbody {
    display:block; /* this is what causes the problem */
    max-height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: yeah possible bug but you also have other issues in your HTML. You have your <td class="name" colspan="2"> set to span 2 cols when it shouldn't span any at all.

Comment: By formatting it with `display:block` you’re explicitly telling the `tbody` to _not_ behave like a table body element, but like a normal block element instead … so I don’t think you can expect the behavior that is to be expected from a table body here.

Comment: you are right.. I made that mistake when making the demo table. The real table has images, but I didnt want to have to add alot of images to my question or jsfiddle. The real problem is with the Display:block; but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

defaut display of tbody is `table-row-group`, if you change it or set `tbody` in `absolute` or `fixed` `position`, it will not be part of the table-layout anymore.

In the flow with a reset on `display`, it will have the space of a first cell left. Browser will still try to keep coherent the layout. and will leave a gap for the missing cells.

You can try some work around, like using `table-layout` on table, so you can set you `tbody block` on 100% width. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fT3EC/4/)**

`tbody tr` can optionnaly be set as `display:table`.

Anyhow, `tbody` will be off the flow of it's parent `table`, and columns will not be sized the same in tbody and theader

**[and with 3rd col overflowing](http://jsfiddle.net/fT3EC/5/)**
[image: table layout bent]

*[some cloning with jquery to avoid splitting table ?](http://jsfiddle.net/fT3EC/7/)*

Comment: Using 'display:table-row-group' instead of 'display:block' fixed a similar colspan issue I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your table into three tables 
One for the header
One for the body 
One for the Footer

Then put a div around the body table which will allow you to control things like `overflow: scroll;` correctly

Comment: splitting table kills the relation in between thead, tbody and tfoot , then no point to have 3 tables where contents are not related anymore

Comment: right... it is a trade-off between the desired functionality and the relationship.

Comment: Else maybe instead of splitting, you may use cloning via jquery http://jsfiddle.net/fT3EC/6/ .... not an advise, more like talking :)

Answer (score 0):

Forget the hacks, just don't use a table.  Create a grid with divs, then you can have the behavior you want and it can be styled to look exactly the way you want.

Comment: if data deserves to be layed into a table , why should you drop it ? table elements style can be reset like any others tag

Comment: I can't argue with that logic and your final solution with clone() is quite elegant. +1 for that. I guess my point was if the behavior desired was more important than say, accessibility (or semantics as you point out), to the OP, then stop trying to hack a table into producing a behavior it wasn't designed to support.  Again, really nice on the final solution.

Comment: thanks for your feed back , i wasn't too proud of that cloning idea ;)